# how to split the strings in ruby?. I have a string ["1.6.0_43 /opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/bin/java\n"]

Tags: ruby

I have a requirement to split the string from

```
["1.6.0_43 /opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/bin/java\n"]
```

to

```
1.6.0_43 /opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/bin/java
```

like this. How can i do that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Is the input an array of a single String? Your comment below makes it sound like it's not. The desired result isn't a valid String, or other Ruby type so you can't get there either. Please fix your question so it makes more sense.

Comment: From where are you getting that string? You sure you don't just have an array with a string in it?

Comment: Is original "string" a string that has brackets in it (`[` and `]`) and quotes (`"`) like this: `"[\"string\"]"` (quotes (`"`) in the inside are escaped (`\"`)) OR an array that has 1 string like this: `["string"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Is the requirement to remove the trailing `\n`? If so, one easy way to do that is with `gsub`:

```
"1.6.0_43 /opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/bin/java\n/".gsub("\n", "") returns "1.6.0_43 /opt/oracle/agent12c/core/12.1.0.4.0/jdk/bin/java"
```

The Ruby docs for the [String class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html) are very helpful.

Comment: And also i need to remove these quotes"  " and [ ]